# Changing variables after checking them with 'if' python

Tags: python

Hi I am quite new to python and I am getting an error when I try to change a variable after checking it with 'if'. (note I only just started python I mostly only do lua)

so this is an example that didn't work for me

```
var = 5

if var == 5:
  var = var + 1
  return
```

This is works in lua for me so I am confused.

In lua its

```
var = 5 

if var == 5 then
  var = var + 1
end
```

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just remove `return`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @RobinSage To make `var` 6 when `var` is 5.

Comment: _What_ error? If that code is not inside a function then I'd expect a syntax error, for example, but in that case the error message tells you exactly what the problem is: it's not in a function.

Comment: i need to get 6 as the output

Comment: it is inside 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

I am making a discord bot so this will trigger when someone sends a message.

The function is inside this.

Comment: One point you may be missing is that Lua variables are global by default and have to be declared as local if that is what you want. Python variables are by default local to the function they are bound in, and have to be declared as global if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
#In this example, return is not needed
var = 5
if var == 5:
  var = var + 1
print(var)


#use return when using a function as per the example below
def my_var():
    var = 5
    if var == 5:
        var = var + 1
        return var
res = my_var()
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [return](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/) here. Why is it there? It's not a function. You don't have to retun anything. The variable though is being updated.

```
var = 5

if var == 5:
  var = var + 1
print(var)
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO, I think you should be posting your question along with the error that you are getting, which will give more context.

I can see you have used **return**, are you using this inside a function, i dont think it is needed otherwise?